# Stacking one picture box on another in the designer view

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a strange problem with my PictureBox controls where I am trying to stack one on top of the other in the designer view. With the first PictureBox I have an image as well as with the second one but when I stack the second one on top of the first one they seem to be switching places as if the one underneath is moved forward.

Any way of preventing this?

Comment: Well, that's unusual.  Use View + Other Windows + Document Layout for another view of the control order.  It supports drag+drop to move stuff around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click on one and choose "Send to Back."

That changes the order in which the controls are added to the form's Controls list in the .Designer.cs file.

Controls at the end of the list are farther down the Z order (towards the back).